# Error in importing a Angular custom pipe from a shared folder

Tags: angular, typescript, module, single-page-application, angular9

I created a custom pipe from a shared folder to use it in component 1 (example: Applicant component) HTML, so I imported it to **ApplicantModule**. My goal, is for this pipe to be reusable in component 2 (example: Applicant component) so I also import this custom pipe to component's 2 module which is **CoApplicantModule**. After compiling I got console error.

[image]

When I tried to move the import statement of the custom pipe to **SharedModule** and tried the pipe from component 2, I got a console error.
[image]

I would like to ask for your help since couldn't find the error for this one because I assume that it will work since **SharedModule** was also imported **ApplicantModule** and **CoApplicantModule**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare your `pipe` in more than one `module` . You can create a `module` for all your *custom pipes*, then just import it in all the components you need to use them.

---

I usually create a directory in order to keep things organized. In this case **pipes** directory.

**pipes/pipes.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyCustomPipe } from './myCustom.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyCustomPipe],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [MyCustomPipe],
  exports: [MyCustomPipe]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

---

Now, you can reuse this in any of your components. For example:

**pages/home/home.module.ts**

```
...
import { PipesModule } from "../../pipes/pipes.module";
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    PipesModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Now, they are already available here.

**pages/home/home.page.html**

```
...
<p>{{ something | myCustomPipe }}</p>
...
```

Comment: In this example I'm talking about just one module, but you can always create different modules for different pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says you that you have declared `pipe` in 2 modules. You got solution in your error message. You can create another module where you add your `pipe` to `declarations` and then you export it in `exports` and instead of "importing" your `pipe` by `declarations` you just import created module in `imports`.